# No ImageMagick installation available in TYPO3, I can't resize the images

Tags: typo3, image-resizing, typo3-6.1.x

I am very new in TYPO3 world (I came from Joomla and WordPress)

I noticed that after inserting an image in a page, if I resize it, after that I save the page, the image come back to its original size.

Reading on Internet seems to me that this thing may depend by ImageMagick configuration.

So if I go into my administration panel and **Install ---> Basic Configuration** in the **Check ImageMagick** field say to me:

```
No ImageMagick installation available

It seems that there is no adequate ImageMagick installation available at the checked locations (, /bin, /opt/local/bin/, /usr/X11R6/bin/, /usr/bin, /usr/bin/, /usr/local/bin, /usr/local/bin/)
An 'adequate' installation for requires 'convert', 'combine'/'composite' and 'identify' to be available
```

is this the problem? What can I do to solve it?

Tnx

Andrea

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to... install the [ImageMagick](http://www.imagemagick.org/) on your computer and after that configure it in `All configuration` section of Install Tool - at least these params:

- `im_path` it's the folder where ie. `convert` exists, in unix terminal you can determine that with command `which convert`
- `im_version_5` most probably it will be `im6`

Also ask your host where you are gonna to deploy your production version what is the IM path, if they doesn't support IM, change the host!

Comment: at this time I am execute it in local on my Ubuntu system. So have I to download form here: http://www.imagemagick.org/script/binary-releases.php#unix ? and then install? the problem is that in this link I only find the RedHat version and not for Ubuntu binary...

Comment: o.O ubuntu has a package in apt, hasn't it? Searching for `ubuntu install imagemagick` in google returns links to official documentation and also many posts on forums and blogs... try: `sudo apt-get install imagemagick`

Comment: mmm yesterday I have install it from source and the installation seems ended ok,so I have setted the two parameters of you told me about. And, after some changing in Install ---> IAll Configuration (in whic I say to use IM and not gdlib) now I can correctly resize my immages !!! The only strange think is that if I go into Install ---> Immage Processing tab, if I try to execute the test (for example: Scaling images ) it go into error and say me:

Comment: There was no result from the ImageMagick operation
Below there's a dump of the ImageMagick commands executed: '/usr/local/bin/convertconvert' +profile '*' -geometry 150x120!   '/var/www/Typo3/typo3/sysext/install/imgs/jesus2_transp.gif'[0] '/var/www/Typo3/typo3temp/pics/install_scale_gif.gif'

but the strange thing is that in Typo3 now it work and scale the immage, why?

Answer (score 0):

Another solution and for me the better solution is to use GraphicsMagick, you can install a precompiled version vie FTP and don't need to change host.. plus better image quality, faster.. http://www.graphicsmagick.org/